# Annotation to check for uncalled method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Consider the following class

```
Class  Student{
     private String name = null;

     public boolean hasName(){
         return name != null;
     }

     //Something to warn me that hasName() should be called before getName()
     public String getName(){
         return name;
     }
 }
```

Please don't answer me to call `hasName()` inside `getName()`. I just want an annotation that shows me a warning in android studio saying **You should call `hasName()` before calling `getName()`**. Is there something like that?

Comment: Its probably an error since you are returning an `String` whereas the return type is `boolean`

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo due to copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

//edit::

you can also enforce the order of the method calls by using the FixMethodOrder like so, but you must have the names in ascending order:

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;\

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

@Test
public void firstTest() {
    System.out.println("first");
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    System.out.println("second");
}
```

}

the best way to do this would be to call it in the method.. however, you do not want this... so you are just trying to get something to tell the programmer (you) that you need to make sure there is a name before you call getName()?

you can simply add a comment? otherwise you would have to generate an error message to the user, which would only be relevant if the hasName() returns false, and the only way to test this is to test whether it is false or not, which would require calling the method or simply testing for nullity like so:

```
public String getName() {
    if(name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: The question is not for tests but for a general case.